# Why am I iterating less times than expected?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have printed out my `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` and receive the number three, but when I pass my array into my function it prints out 2 when stored into a variable and therefor iterates one less time than it should.

```
 void printAry(int ary[])
 {
     int size = sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0]);
       cout<<size;//size will print out 2! why?
       for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
     {
         cout<<ary[i];
     }
 }

 int main() {
     int ary[3] = {1,2,3};
     cout<<sizeof(ary[0]);

     return 0;
 }
```

Why is it iterating one time less than expected ?

Comment: The array is being interpreted as a _pointer_ inside the function, hence the problem. Even worse, you're passing _a single member_ of `ary` to the function, not the whole array.

Comment: `ary` is pointer in `printAry`, not `array of int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that *arrays decay into pointers*.

Basically

```
void printAry(int ary[])
```

is equivalent to:

```
void printAry(int* ary)
```

So `sizeof(ary)` is equal to the size of pointer to `int` on your system.

Comment: If you don't mind: I've added "pointer to `int`" as not all pointers *necessarily* need to be the same size.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, for example pointers to functions hypothetically may have another size. Good point!

Comment: It's true for primitives too, e.g. `sizeof(int*)` might be different to `sizeof(long*)`.

Comment: @Bathsheba is it guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: I wouldn't bet my job on it, but I'm sure the standard allows for `sizeof(int*)` to be different to `sizeof(long*)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `sizeof(ary) / sizeof(ary[0])` idiom if `ary` is a function parameter since it will have already *decayed* into a pointer type: `sizeof(ary)` is merely the size of a pointer to `int` on your platform.

In C, you need to pass the size information explicitly, or adopt a convention that a particular value signals the end of the array (cf. `'\0'` in the C standard library string functions.)

In C++, you can use a `std::vector`.